# Dynamic Trash icon in Dash to Dock on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, trash, dash-to-dock

I want to make a trash icon for my dock. **Dash to Dock** does not have a trash icon that I can add, so I was going to make one.  I want the *Trash full* icon when something gets added to the trash, and I want the *Trash Empty* icon for when there is nothing in the trash.  Can somebody please tell me how to do this?
Here is my desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Trash
Comment=Trash
Icon=user-trash
Exec=nautilus trash://
Categories=Utility;
Actions=trash;

[Desktop Action trash]
Name=Empty Trash
Exec=/home/zacharygough/trash.sh -e
```

Comment: You could use `Gio.FileMonitor`  to watch `/home/$USER/.local/share/Trash`. Don't forget to change the icon from idle, or else you'll have occasional crashes. What language are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a noob at this kind of stuff...  Can you tell me how to use it?  Also, I'm just using basic .desktop file configurations.

Comment: Ah, I see, you have this as a launcher, not programmatically. You'll need something programmatically though. Possibly you can make it change the icon in the .desktop file, if triggered. Teaching for the next few hours, I'll see if I can post a tiny script later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Automatically change the icon of a .desktop file, depending on the state of the trash can

[image]
[image]

The tiny scrip uses `Gio.Filemonitor` to watch the state (empty or not) of `trash:///`

*How to use*

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, name it `watchout.py`
2. Replace in the lines:

   ```py
   # edit path to .desktop files and icon names below
   self.fpath = "/home/jacob/Desktop/test.desktop"
   self.iconempty = "user-trash"
   self.iconfull = "user-trash-full"
   ```

   ...the `self.fpath`, and if you want the `self.iconempty` and the `self.iconfull`
3. Run the script with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/watchout.py
   ```

That's it!

If all works fine, add the very same command to Startup Applications.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import Gio, GLib

class SetTrashIcon:

    def __init__(self):
        # edit path to .desktop file and icon names below
        self.fpath = "/home/jacob/Desktop/test.desktop"
        self.iconempty = "user-trash"
        self.iconfull = "user-trash-full"
        # don't edit below
        self.trashdir = Gio.File.new_for_uri("trash:///")
        monitor = self.trashdir.monitor_directory(0, None)
        monitor.connect("changed", self.actonfile)
        self.currempty = None
        self.check_empty()
        loop = GLib.MainLoop()
        loop.run()

    def replace(self, newicon):
        # set the new icon, replace the Icon- line
        text = open(self.fpath).read()
        toreplace = [s for s in text.split() if s.startswith("Icon=")][0]
        newtext = text.replace(toreplace, "Icon=" + newicon)
        open(self.fpath, "wt").write(newtext)

    def set_icon(self, newempty):
        # if trash state changes, decide which icon to set
        if newempty != self.currempty:
            if newempty:
                self.replace(self.iconempty)
            else:
                self.replace(self.iconfull)
            self.currempty = newempty

    def check_empty(self):
        # check if trash is empty
        newempty = len(list(self.trashdir.enumerate_children(
            "standard::*", Gio.FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE, None
        ))) == 0
        self.set_icon(newempty)

    def actonfile(self, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None, arg4=None):
        # act on changes in the trash content
        if arg4 == Gio.FileMonitorEvent.ATTRIBUTE_CHANGED:
            self.check_empty()

SetTrashIcon()
```

Comment: Nice. I might adapt it with a fuel gauge where you could set 4gb or whatever as full.