# New blue trash icon in 22.10?

Tags: icons

I just realized after using `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding show-trash true` on my 22.10 release, there is this blue trash icon on the desktop instead of your normal grey one.

[image: blue trash icon in 22.10]

The normal one:

[image: grey icon in taskbar 22.10]

Is this a new icon or something I discovered?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and looking through the `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/.../places`, the 256x256 and 512x512 ones must have been overwritten during the update.

You could replace the icon by right clicking the Trash under Properties, by clicking the icon, the file picker will pop up and choose the corresponding Yaru icon for trash. However, this doesn't account for the different states.

[The whole 22.04 Yaru package containing the icons for download.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/yaru-theme-icon/download) You can convert to .deb to .zip using [Convertio.co](https://convertio.co) and the last high res trash icons are there to replace.

This is the [Ask Ubuntu tip on how to change the trash icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201596/dynamic-trash-icon-in-dash-to-dock-on-ubuntu-18-04) effectively, depending on the state of the trash can.

Instead, I solved by managing and replacing files with privileged access. Launch the file app through the terminal by entering `sudo nautilus`, and overwrite the files specifically under `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/256x256/places` and `/status`, `/usr/share/icons/Yaru/256x256@2/places` and `/status` with ones with the same name and location from the converted package file.

Refresh the GUI by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>R</kbd>. Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you for the edits.  Much better!  (Tip:  You can click the "flag" icon beside this comment and mark it  as "no longer needed" after reading)